# Saving H.264 RTP stream without re-encoding?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, h.264, rtp

My C++ application receives a H.264 RTP video stream.

Right now it decodes the stream, saves it into a YUV file and later I use ffmpeg to re-ecode the file into something suitable to watch on a Windows PC (eg. Mpeg4 AVI).

Shouldn't it be possible to save the H.264 stream into a AVI (or similar) container without having to decode and re-encode it ? That would require some H.264 decoder on the PC to watch, but it should be much more efficient.

How could that be done ? Are there any libraries supporting that ?

Comment: I think `mencoder` can take H.264 and put it into AVI container without decoding, with `-ovc copy`. `mencoder` is open source, so you can take a look there.

Comment: @liori Yes, the whole 10 MB source code are OpenSource... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your program could pipe the rtp itself through `ffmpeg` - even invoking it using [`popen3()`](http://sites.google.com/site/williamedwardscoder/popen3).

It seems that you need to use an [intermediate SDP file](http://ffmpeg-users.933282.n4.nabble.com/Does-ffmpeg-support-RTP-input-td2279252.html) - I speculate that you can specify a file you created as a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe) or with [`tmpfile()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184702/how-to-generate-a-good-random-seed-to-pass-to-srand/2184727#2184727) which your application writes to - using the file as an intermediary.

The command-line would be *something* like:

```
int p[3];
const char* const out_fmt = "avi";
const char* cmd[] = {"ffmpeg","-f",,"-i",temp_sdp_filename,"-vcodec","copy","-f",out_fmt,"-",NULL};
if(-1 == popen3(p,cmd)) ...
// write the rtp that you receive to p[STDIN_FILENO]
// read the avi from p[STDOUT_FILENO]
// read any messages and error text from p[STDERR_FILENO]
```

I believe that in this circumstance ffmpeg is clever enough to repackage the container (rtp stream vs AVI) without transcoding the video and audio (this is the `-vcodec copy` switch); therefore, you'd have no loss of quality and it'd be blazingly fast.

Comment: My ffmpeg only allows the rtp format for output, but not for input. ALso, I believe to read from stdin, ffmpeg need "-i -", not just "-".

Comment: @Gene Vincent yeah googling gives little hint

Answer (score 1):

using ffmpeg is correct but the answers posted so far dont look right to me.

the correct switch should be:

```
-vcodec copy
```